# Microsoft Excel - I am looking to do a vlookup using only part of the string in the columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am looking for help with a formula that only takes the last name(column has both first and last name) as a lookup_value and uses that as the key to find a name in a table where the column also has a first and last name. The reason I am looking to do this is there are certain differences in the table array. See below for more details.

I have tried to use a vlookup with this formula `=RIGHT(C6,LEN(C6)-FIND(" ",C6,1))` imbedded as that formula can extract the last name from the lookup value. I am open to other suggestions though

[image]

Comment: "I am looking for help with a formula" OK well you've come to the right place - what formula are you looking for help with, and where do you need the help? Please [edit] your question to include details on what you've tried so far and where you've run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks @AlexM. I have updated

Comment: Your formula seems like it will extract the last name. What is your problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find a way to use Regular Expressions in Excel.

With Google Spreadsheets you can extract the last word in a string with something:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E2," \w+$")
```

Although, you have to check if the lastname has two or more words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(C6,FIND(" ",C6)-1)&" "&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C6," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```